# Organizing, Storing, and Keeping Track of code for reuse

Tags: code-reuse, code-organization

Many moons ago I started storing my music as MP3’s.  I downloaded like mad and just dumped them all into a folder.  After collecting thousands of songs I had a big mess.  After two years of organizing all music in my free time I have made it to “D” section of my library.  I am starting to write code on a daily basis and I would like to keep a lot of what I do for reuse and future reference.  I use Visual Studio a lot, and Eclipse sometimes, but I also do web development.  Right now I am just have a folder on an external drive called `Projects` and inside that folder I have code I want to save broken down by its respective IDE and then the language it was developed in.  This is working ok right now, but I fear after a few years it might get hard to navigate, and I don’t want another mess like my music library.  **What are some good ways to keep track of code and programming projects while also promoting easy navigation and future reuse?**

Comment: @jtbndes Added, also added subjective tag.

Comment: I was thinking about the same problem today.  It's not really custom tailored to this purpose, but I am going to start using google docs to store my code snippets, since I already have a google account.  I'd love to see some good answers to this question, in case there's something better.

Comment: I have a couple of friends (who are admittedly better programmers than myself) who use Google Code, but I have never been a big fan of online services like that.  If everything hits the fan I want all my stuff with me, not on some distant server.

Comment: Incidentally, do your MP3s have metadata?  If so, there are lots of products that will organize it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a subversion repository for purpose of saving code for the future. In my repository I have the following folder structure:

```
\
|- Project1\
|- - Trunk\
|- - Branches\
|- - Tags\
|- Project2\
....
```

This is working for me and I have big and small projects that I coded on since high school in this repository. If I for instance want to port a project that I coded on Linux to Windows I create a branch that I for example call Win32-port. And when I have a 1.0 release of a project I create a tag named 1.0.

Using this method you can also set up back-up scripts and save a backup to another location. (I use a cron job and some python scripts to achieve this, but it all depends on what system the server uses.)

A book about subversion are freely available here: [Link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I hear a lot about subversion, but I have never checked up on it... Guess I will now :)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, there's the beautiful [Snippets](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628015052/http://www.snippetsapp.com:80/?):

[image: snippets]
<sub>(source: [snippetsapp.com](http://www.snippetsapp.com/static/images/screenshots/Snippets.png))</sub>

Also, the new [Xcode 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325023052/https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) will have native support for custom code snippets.

Comment: Thought that the Visual Studio comment would have given it away, but I should have specified anyway that I am a Windows man :)  This may be good info for others that read this though.

Answer (score 0):

It won't really solve your organising problem, but you'll be more productive anyway by using snippet be it inside Eclipse or inside Visual Studio.

Here's a short tutorial for snippet in Eclipse : http://www.dansshorts.com/post/creating-snippets-in-eclipse

And here the explanation to create them and link them to a keyword in Visual Studio 2010 : http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/02/create-snippet-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 0):

This would take a bit more infrastructure to set up and is more for multiple people working together, but the best approach is to start thinking of Software as a Service.

For commonly used functions, wrap them as a web service with good documentation. For instance, if you have a phone validator that seems to be constantly used across projects, it would become part of your validator service.

With few exceptions, most shops don't seem to organize/share code effectively with static document type code libraries.

This would also force you to refactor the code snippets into reusable methods instead of just random code that is copied/pasted in. It also gives you a clean seperation between the public interface and private implementation.